# How make steps calendar diagram in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

The data is for the moment registered in raw I still have to make it dynamic but I would like to make a kind of diagram with the data present. Like in this picture:

[image]

I don't really know where to start I tried to look for diagrams but nothing really matches...

Here is my code:

```js
<template>
    <v-row>
        <v-col cols="5" lg="8" md="6" sm="5" class="months">
                <div  v-for="(month) in months" :key=month.id :value="month" class="month">
                    <h3>{{month.month}}</h3>
                </div>
        </v-col>
        <v-container style="max-width: 100%; height: 420px;" class="overflow-y-auto scrollbar-hidden card-association">
            <p v-for="(s) in sowing" :key="s.id" :value="s">Sowing : {{s.start[0] === 1 ? "January" : ""}} to {{s.end[0] === 5 ? "May" : ""}}</p>
            <p v-for="(p) in planting" :key="p.id" :value="p">Planting : {{p.start[0] === 3 ? "March" : ""}} to {{p.end[0] === 8 ? "August" : ""}}</p>
            <p v-for="(h) in harvesting" :key="h.id" :value="h">Harvesting : {{h.start[0] === 7 ? "July" : ""}} to {{h.end[0] === 11 ? "November" : ""}}</p>
        </v-container>
    </v-row>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

    export default {
        props: {
        },
        data: () => ({
            months: [
                {id: 1, month:'January'},  
                {id: 2, month:'February'},
                {id: 3, month:'March'},
                {id: 4, month:'April'},
                {id: 5, month:'May'},
                {id: 6, month:'June'},
                {id: 7, month:'July'},
                {id: 8, month:'August'},
                {id: 9, month:'September'},
                {id: 10, month:'October'},
                {id: 11, month:'November'},
                {id: 12, month:'December'}
            ],
            sowing: [],
            planting: [],
            harvesting: [],
        }),
        computed: {
            console: () => console,
            ...mapGetters({
                plantActive: 'permatheque/getPlant',            
            }),
            
        },
        methods: {
            async getPlantStepSowing() {
                this.$axios.$get('/lnk/plant/steps?plant_id_id='+this.plantActive.id+'&step_title=Sowing')
                .then(response => {
                    this.sowing = response
                    console.log(this.sowing)
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                });           
            },
            async getPlantStepPlanting() {
                this.$axios.$get('/lnk/plant/steps?plant_id_id='+this.plantActive.id+'&step_title=Planting')
                .then(response => {
                    this.planting = response
                    console.log(this.planting)
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                });           
            },
            async getPlantStepHarvesting() {
                this.$axios.$get('/lnk/plant/steps?plant_id_id='+this.plantActive.id+'&step_title=Harvesting')
                .then(response => {
                    this.harvesting = response
                    console.log(this.harvesting)
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                });           
            },
            

        },
        mounted() {
            this.getPlantStepSowing();
            this.getPlantStepPlanting();
            this.getPlantStepHarvesting();
        }
    }
</script>
```

And what it looks like now:

[image]

And here is an example of what I get in response with the API:

```
    [
  {
    "id": 9,
    "plant_id": {
      "id": 136,
      "name": "Basilic"
    },
    "start": [
      7
    ],
    "end": [
      11
    ],
    "step_title": "Harvesting",
    "step_order": 3,
    "step_subtitle": "Récolte",
    "help": ""
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using Vuetify? There is a [range slider component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/range-sliders/#slots) that looks exactly like what you need. Make it `readonly` and style accordingly.

Alternatively, you can use timeline charts. [Here is an example](https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/timeline-charts/distributed/) from Apex Charts that looks pretty close to what you need.

Comment: Thanks I will look for Range Slider component in vuetify. I tried apex charts but failed to implement it maybe because I'm using nuxt.js?

Comment: I haven't worked with nuxt.js but see this [Github issue](https://github.com/apexcharts/vue-apexcharts/issues/34)

Comment: Thank you very much i will try it.  I would accept your answer if I succeeded, thanks again